# How use a converter in xaml Xamarin.form

Tags: xaml, colors, xamarin.forms, converters

i have several entry that i must color with red or green (it depends if the value is positive or negative). I created a Converter in the project, in the same folder where other converter is already created (the project is not just mine).
Now I tried so:

```
<my:SingolaRigaCollapsed Even="False" Height="40"  HeaderText="Variazione patrimoniale &#x0a; al lordo dei proventi" ValueText="{Binding RendimentoAlLordoProventi}" ValueColor="{Binding RendimentoAlLordoProventi, Converter={StaticResource ValueToColorConverter}}"/>
```

*RendimentiAlLordoProventi* is a string, and i'l like to set the valuecolor depending on the string's value.

The converter is this:

```
class ValueToColorConverters : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString().Contains("-") ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Acting like this, the program crash on xaml loading, i don't know if it's because of the incorrect binding in ***ValueColor*** property, or for something else.

P.s. the name of the converter is hand-inserted; I don't know why, but this was the only converter that VS doesn't find

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it going wrong in your code, but I guess it can be one of two things:

1. You didn't declare the converter in your page or globally in the app.

To do this, add this part to your page:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ValueToColorConverter x:Key="ValueToColorConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And don't forget to add the converters namespace to the root of your app, like: `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourApp.Namespace.Converters"`

Now you should be able to use it like you are doing now.

2. Something is going wrong in you convert itself.

I see you are doing this: `return value.ToString().Contains("-") ? Color.Red : Color.Green;`

What happens if `value` is `null`? Right now, your app will blow up. Because it takes in an object, you have to take care of all possible scenarios. Cast it to the right type, make sure it is not null, etc.

If you want it more typed, have a look at [MFractor](http://docs.mfractor.com/xamarin-forms/value-converter-type-safety/). This Visual Studio for Mac extension provides you with type-safety for your converters.

Comment: i'm not able to add that code in a WP page.
Now, i tryed to add this line:

    xmlns:conv="using:PROJ.WP.Converters"

but it's not working yet. now i'm gopin to try again the execution so i can tell you what the error is

Comment: What is a WP page? And why are you not able to add it?

Comment: This app has a mix of Xamarin.Forms code, and Xamarin.WP code (shared and native, i really don't know why). The page where i'm working now doesn't allow ContentPage tag.

i can't add the ContentPage.Resource tag

Comment: mmmh nothing, i can't tell you the crashing error, because i see noone.

Comment: Instead of `ContentPage` put the page you are actually using.

Comment: in this page i have UserControlPage (that i think is a custom page).
I cannot use the x:key property because is already used from an inner section.
And i don't know why, but i'm not able to find my converter class:

        <ResourceDictionary conv:ValueToColorConverters/>
that, produce an error

Comment: Because that is not the right syntax. Please do not try to just copy and paste a solution, but try to understand what you are doing.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry but i could only find conv instead of convert, and i assumed that was the same thing with different name (between native and portable). the name after conv referes to the class, so i moved the file with this class into the using references used below in the code (now the namespaces match). I'm trying to understand, the problem is only that i don't know everything